# Qt function runJavaScript() does not execute JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, html, qt, qtwebengine

I am trying to implement the displaying of a web page in Qt. I chose to use the Qt WebEngine to achieve my task. Here's what I did :

- Wrote a sample web page consisting of a empty form.
- Wrote a JS file with just an API to create a radio button inside the form.

In my code, it looks like this :

```
View = new QWebEngineView(this);
// read the js file using qfile
file.open("path to jsFile");
myJsApi = file.Readall();
View->page()->runjavascript (myjsapi);
View->page()->runjavascript ("createRadioButton(\"button1\");");
```

I find that the `runJavaScript()` function has no effect on the web page. I can see the web page in the output window, but the radio button I expected is not present. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you will have to connect the signal [`loadFinished(bool)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#loadFinished) of your `page()` to a slot, then execute `runJavaScript()` in this slot.

```
void yourClass::mainFunction()
{
    View = new QWebEngineView(this);

    connect( View->page(), SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), this, SLOT(slotForRunJS(bool)));
}

void yourClass::slotForRunJS(bool ok)
{
    // read the js file using qfile
    file.open("path to jsFile");
    myJsApi = file.Readall();
    View->page()->runJavaScript(myjsapi);
    View->page()->runJavaScript("createRadioButton(\"button1\");");
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it! Feel free to accept the answer if it suited you, as it can help other people as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, `runJavascript` didn't have any effect. I had to put some html content into the view (with `page().setHtml("")` before running it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the application output, it might contain JavaScript errors. Even if your JS code is valid, you might encounter the situation where the script is run before `DOMContentLoaded` event, that is `document.readyState == 'loading'`. Therefore, the DOM might not be available yet, as well as variables or functions provided by other scripts. If you depend on them for your code to run, when you detect this `readyState`, either wait for the event or try calling the function later, after a timeout. The second approach with timeout might be needed if you need to get the result of the code execution, as this can be done only synchronously.